# Find by value on leveldb

Tags: node.js, database, key-value-store, leveldb

I've been playing with leveldb and it's really good at what it's designed to do--storing and getting key/value pairs based on keys.

But now I want to do something more advanced and find myself immediately stuck. Is there no way to find a record by value? The only way I can think of is to iterate through the entire database until I find an entry with the value I'm looking for. This becomes worse if I'm looking for multiple entries with the value (basically a "where" query) since I have to iterate through the entire database every time I try to do this type of query.

Am I trying to do what Leveldb isn't designed to do and should I be using another database instead? Or is there a nice way to do this?

Comment: what library are you using to interact with leveldb? maybe i can update my answer to direct javascript API. FWIW, wiredtiger makes working with key-value store much easier http://source.wiredtiger.com/3.0.0/schema.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right. Basically what you need to know about is **key composition**.

Second, you don't query by value itself in SQL `WHERE` clause, but using a boolean query like `age = 42`.

To answer your particlular question imagine you have a first key-value namespace in leveldb, where you store your objects where the value is serialized in json for instance:

```
 key                    |          value
-------------------------------------------------
 namespace |    uid     |          value
================================================
 users     |    1       | {name:"amz", age=32}
------------------------------------------------
 users     |    2       | {name:"abki", age=42}
```

In another namespace, you index users uid by age:

```
         key              | value
----------------------------------
 namespace    | age | uid | value
==================================
 users-by-uid |  32 | 1   | empty
----------------------------------
 users-by-uid |  42 | 2   | empty
```

Here the value is empty because, the key must be unique. What we could think as the value of the given rows would be `uid` column it's composed
into the key to make each row's key unique.

In that second namespace, every key that *starts with* the `(user-by-uid, 32)` match records that answer the query `age = 32`.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood correctly, but does this mean i have to create a reverse index for all the entries I need to make this type of query on?

Comment: Yes. You have to

Comment: Got it, one more quick question. Is this a common practice when using LevelDB? Or are you just suggesting one solution that could solve this problem. I guess I'm curious if I am trying to use LevelDB for the wrong purpose and it's not meant to be used this way (and i should be using another type of DB).

Comment: Well, leveldb is low level, and key composition is the pattern that must be put into practice to develop your high level schemas on top the key/value paradigm

Comment: I give an example use of key composition for storing multiple tables in single kv (through namespace) and indexing value by attribute (aka secondary indices). All of this is an instance of key composition.